# What is domU and why is it connected to my database?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I'm running SQL Server in Amazon EC2. I was taking a look at netstat (`netstat -f`) to sample the active connections on my local database. Everything looks as I would hope, except for an unexpected entry that appears related to EC2:

(All numbers below are modified so as to protect my actual server info).

```
Proto Local Address      Foreign Address                                   State
...
TCP   89.123.45.67:890   domU-12-34-56-78-90-12.compute-3.internal:56789   ESTABLISHED
...
```

`89.123.45.67:890` would be my local database address and port in this case.

Anything.compute-x.internal clearly looks EC2-related. Note that I do not have any CloudWatch alarms or load balancing associated with this server. So the question is-- what is this domU connection and why is it connected to my database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DomU is a Xen term - it's a virtual machine.  The name you see really has nothing to do with that, though.  `netstat` does a reverse IP lookup on the remote end of the connection; this name is what the remote IP resolved to.  Add a `-n` flag to `netstat` to see the actual IP address that connected.

Comment: Ah, seems some internal host names are prefixed with `ip-` while others are `domU-`. The `ip-` named were clearly my other instances, but the `domU-` at first glance didn't appear to be such. The IP address matched up though. Mystery solved. Thanks.